# Angular 2 Beta0 - Cant get Event Emitters to work

Tags: events, angular

This is driving me nuts.  I have an *Angular2 application* that I am trying to finish the login feature on.  All I'm trying to do at this point is update the *Navbar* component template with the logged in users username when they login successfully.  I am attempting to use EventEmitter to do this but the *subscribe* part never fires.

**Everything builds/compiles OK - no errors.  And the navbar does update, but only after a hard refresh.  I'm trying to update it without the user needing to refresh**

**LoginService**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

   constructor(..., private userService: UserService) {
      //
   }

   postLogin(f: ControlGroup) {
      // Submits Login Form Etc.
      // Calls UserService to 'Set User'
      this.userService.setUser(user);
   }
}
```

**UserService**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    // My EventEmitter Here (I've tried without @Ouput() too)
    @Output() userChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
        //
    }

    setUser(user: any) {
        // Do some stuff with user
        this.localStorage.setObject('user', user);

        // Emit User Change Event (This logs to console OK)
        console.log('Emitting User');
        this.userChange.emit({ user: user });
    }
}
```

**NavBar Component** 
This is where I want to update User on Event Fire.

```
@Component({
    selector: "navbar",
    directives: [<any>RouterLink, <any>NgIf],
    providers: [UserService],
    template: require('./index.html'),
    //... I've tried 'events:[], inputs:[], properties[] - No success
})

export class Navbar {

    /**
     * @type {}
     */
    user: any = {};


    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        let self = this;

        // I expect this to log to console, but never does
        userService.userChange.subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('Caught Event');
            self.user = data.user;
        });
    }
}
```

**Navbar Template**

```
<!-- User Authed Menu -->
<li *ngIf="loggedIn" class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" (click)="userDrop = !userDrop" href="#" role="button">
        {{ user.username }}
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" [hidden]="!userDrop">
        <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['./Login']" (click)="userDrop = !userDrop">Logout</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

NavbarComponent is under an AppComponent as well, not sure if that matters.

I have also tried just updating a user object on the shared UserService and referencing it from nav component, but that wasn't working either.  I have a fairly strong angular 1 background and I am still lost on why this isn't working.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think your NavBar component may be creating its own instance of UserService.  Try removing the `providers:` line, and adding it further up the component tree.  Do you also provide this service (using `providers:`) elsewhere in your component tree?

Comment: Nice!  That was it.  I did have it as a provider for LoginComponent & NavbarComponent. Moving it further up tree allowed the event to be caught.  Thank you very much!

Comment: So now that I have that event being triggered properly, I only need to deal with why its still not updating in the template.  That seems much easier to troubleshoot though.

Comment: Got it, working as intended - thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the OP comments, because the NavBar component has `providers: [UserService]`, it was injecting its own instance of the service.

Removing `providers: [UserService]` from the NavBar component and adding it further up the component tree allows multiple components to share one instance.

For something like a UserService, where you likely only want one instance, you can put `providers: [UserService]` in the root component, or specify the service in the call to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [UserService])`.